# Is it possible to customize Plotly x-axis hoverinfo in Python?

Tags: python, plotly

When I set the *hoverinfo* of a Plotly object to "x+text", I can modify what is shown in the hover tooltip using the *hovertext* attribute.

I haven't found a way to modify the hover text along the x-axis though. I would like to modify it to be more than the default x-axis value at that location.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want to change the ticklabels of x-axis instead of the *hoverinfo*.

The meaning of **x** in *hoverinfo* is the x-coordinated of the points. So if you truly want to revise the **x**, maybe you should change the x-coordinated of the points. Maybe changed into string or some special case.

Of course, you could also use *hovertext* to fully present all the information which you want to present. If you are worried about the *\n* symbol is not working, you could use `<Br>` directly.